# Update Proxy settings from VB application, only works the first time

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, proxy

I've been trying to create a simple program to change the Proxy setting, Enable/disable Proxy. But it only changes the setting the first time.

I've searched the forum and the internet, but no luck.

I've managed to make the program work once, but when calling the ToggleProxy() function a secound time, it first changes the registry accordingly, then when the wininet.dll is called to refresh the setting in Internet Explorer, the old value is put back into the registry.

So, when changing the proxy and updating IE settings, it all works fine, but when trying to change the secound time, it put backs the settings from the first call.

Do i need to close or clear something? if closing the application and starting it again, it works one time again.

Is the wininet.dll/InternetSetOption storing the first call somehow?

Attaching the Dll declaration and the ToggleProxy() function below:

```
'Refresh Internet Options for Webbrowsers
Public Declare Auto Function InternetSetOption Lib "wininet.dll" (hInternet As IntPtr, dwOption As Integer, lpBuffer As IntPtr, dwBufferLength As Integer) As Boolean
Public Const INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED = 39
Public Const INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH = 37


'Toggle the Proxy On/Off
Public Sub ToggleProxy()
    'Declare temp variable as Integer
    Dim setValue As Integer
    ' If EnableProxy regkey is 1, set setvalue to 0, else set to 1.
    If ProxyRegKey = "1" Then
        setValue = "0"
    Else
        setValue = "1"
    End If


    ' Change value in EnableProxy regkey to the value set in setValue    
    Dim autoshell = My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings", True)

    'Set Value fo EnableProxy according to setValue
    autoshell.SetValue("ProxyEnable", setValue)
    autoshell.Close()
    MessageBox.Show("Value is:" & setValue)

    'Re-read the proxy regkey.
    ReadProxyRegKey()

    'Refresh Internet Settings
    InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, IntPtr.Zero, 0)
    InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, IntPtr.Zero, 0)
End Sub
```

Appriciate all help, seems like a simple thing, but drives me crazy.
Regards
Joaqim

Comment: Sorry, i looked for a vb tag and thats the one i found, and read on wikipedia that studio express used it, i'm new to the whole Visual Basic world and i honestly don't know the difference of all teh dialects yet. my misstake. but perhaps you know why i can only change the setting once when running my program?